# What's wrong with OneJar URL?

Tags: java, url, onejar

I always thought that `URL`s can be composed via this [constructor](http://goo.gl/gK1uH2), and with something like

```
new URL(new URL("file:/foo/bar/"), "images/a.png")
```

I get

```
file:/foo/bar/images/a.png
```

as expected.<sup>1</sup> However, from [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net) I obtain a strange looking URL and the result of

```
new URL(new URL("onejar:foo.bar"), "images.a.png")
```

is simply

```
onejar:images.a.png
```

The parent path gets simply dropped. I tried to prefix or suffix the parts with `/` or `.`, but nothing changes. **Update: This isn't true, see below.**

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Do I have to do it via strings (which feels pretty hacky).

### UPDATE:

I see that the trailing slash indeed helps. For whatever reason, `onejar` uses dots as delimiters, but it seems to accept slashes as well. So I can take the original URL like `onejar:foo.bar` convert to a string, append `/`, and convert back to URL. The result can be then composed via the constructor mentioned above, so it seems to be the right way.

---

<sup>1 unless I forget the trailing slash, which I do very often, but this is a different story.</sup>

Comment: Funny: I get a `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: onejar` instead of the result you say you obtained.

Comment: @Giulio Piancastelli: Right... for this to work you have to be actually using OneJar (I guess it gets registered somehow with URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, well, apart from the fact that the constructor you want to invoke uses a `URL` object as first parameter instead of a `String`, I guess the behavior you see may have something to do with the fact that `file` scheme URI are hierarchical, but if you don't provide any hierarchy symbol (i.e. the slash) the constructor gives priority to the spec part (i.e. the second parameter) over the context part (i.e. the first parameter).

For example, when you forget the trailing slash on `file:/foo/bar`, what you really are indicating is file `bar` in directory `foo`. If you pass along a relative path such as `images/a.png`, the constructor combines the two as best as it can: of course it cannot append a relative path to what it believes to be a file, giving as a result `file:/foo/bar/images/a.png`, so it just replaces the `bar` file with the file you passed as second parameter, giving as a result `file:/foo/images/a.png`.

The same applies to your second example: `file:foo.bar` indicates a `foo.bar` file, but when you pass the second parameter representing an `images.a.png` file, the substitution happens as explained in the preceding example, giving a result of `file:images.a.png`. This happens, I believe, because you are missing hierarchy symbols (i.e. slashes) where you need to have them in order to obtain the desired result.

This is really a guess rather than an ol' good informed answer.

However, when you type:

```
URL url = new URL(new URL("file:foo.bar/"), "images.a.png");
System.out.println(url);
```

appending a `/` suffix to one of the parts, as you say you had, the result *indeed* changes, contrary to what you affirm, giving the following result:

```
file:foo.bar/images.a.png
```

which appears to be consistent with my guesses.

Still, since I never used OneJar, from your question is unclear what your input really is, and what you want to obtain as a result.

Comment: There were some errors in my question, which I've just fixed. You're right, thanks.